# Installing an existing EPiServer v6 site and database

Tags: asp.net, database, webforms, episerver, episerver-6-r2

Im totaly new at EPiServer and i have a site that i need to install on my machine. I will develop this site in Webforms as v6 do not support MVC pattern. I have all the files from the project as well as the database but when i launch Deployment Center the only option i have is to instaöll a new site. How do i install an existing one? This site is using Composer templates. I've downloaded and installed the correct version of Composer but i suspect i have to configure it on my the site i want to install via Deployment Center.

I have no clue how to do this and i couldn't find the information i was looking for online..

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You typically use EPiServer's Deployment Center to create new EPiServer websites, to upgrade existing EPiServer websites that are already running on the machine, or to install EPiServer modules onto existing websites.

To deploy an existing EPiServer website to an new environment, where you have the project files and a backup of the database, you do everything outside of Deployment Center:

- Create a new web site in IIS, pointing to the project files on the web server's file system
- Restore the database (if needed) to a SQL Server instance, and update your connectionStrings.config
- Run through all of your configs to ensure you have the proper paths for your web server (for things like the VPP)
- Any other steps to get the site working (such as configuring the hosts file or adding a license file to the webroot)

If you have more questions on EPiServer, you can post messages to the forum at [world.episerver.com](http://world.episerver.com). You might get a quicker response there compared to StackOverflow.